# How to debug block class in config.xml

Tags: magento-1, blocks, debugging

I have in my module's etc/config.xml a block specified as follows:

```
    <blocks>
        <discoverymiles>
            <class>MyFrontName_MyModule_Block</class>
        </discoverymiles>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

But when I refresh (admin) page where I am expecting to see the effects of this block (a grid output), I see nothing (the page loads OK but the grid area is blank)
More worryingly, I am not seeing any error output ANYWHERE. Not on the page itself, not in system.log, not exception.log ... nothing.
Expecting to see some kind of 'Block class not found' error (if the class itself is not found which seems to be a logical explanation for it not loading).

Also if I change the  contents to something random 'Blah', still get no error of any kind ...

How to debug this?

any help much appreciated
g

Comment: Are you talking about a adminhtml ? your grid area is blanck? is this your problem

Answer (score 1):

OK found issue:  tag was not inside  tag so the layout file wasn't being called.